# Changing reference cell in a function

Tags: excel-formula

So, this is my formula: **=IF(E137="013";C105+1;"")**

I want to change C105 cell to cell when the "if" formula is true for the first time and later over and over again. Basically make C105 a variable.  Is there a way without using VBA?

[image: https://imgur.com/a/Oi5ZcAv]

Thanks!

Comment: You want C105 to be a counter, that counts every time E137 is 013?

Comment: Or do you want the C106, then C107 then C108, and so on to be a certain value every time it resolves to true.

Comment: No. Edited - added a photo. My problem is that I am using filter and I cannot autofill the 3th column.(that my goal) This formula was a proposition to fix this problem. Well maybe there is simpler way to omit hidden rows.

Comment: I still do not understand what you are trying to return and where.

Comment: Under 0-01-013-0001  next should be with ending 0002 next 0003 etc... But if I drop the formula down it changes C105 to C106 while I need it to be C137 for the next one. My goal is to fill this column like this changing the last number but I have problem because of the filter.

Comment: do you then want the values to stay static once the filter is removed?

Comment: And will `""` be the outcome for all the other items in column E?  As in if column E equals anything but `013` it will always be blank?  Or are you trying to create a number that is dependent on Column E?  For example it equals `012` are you wanting the `0-01-012-0001` and so on?

Comment: Yes, it is just a code which will stay unchanged

Comment: Yes it is dependent on Column E

Comment: So if Column E was `012` what output do you want?

Comment: 0-01-012-0001 for the first one with 012 and 0-01-012-0002 for the second one with 012 etc..

Comment: what is the first row of data?

Comment: Both are empty C and E columns - my date is incomplete,

Comment: Well you need to fill E then you can use a formula like: `="0-01-"&E2&"-"&TEXT(COUNTIF($E$2:$E2,$E2))` in C where row 2 is the first row of data.

Comment: Well I wanted manually use filter for E and then fill in a series  for C rather than creating a formula for all cases.

Comment: Then fill E that way and put the formula in C.  There is no way to do C the way you want and it is not needed.

Comment: Okey, it works. Thanks!